# PIL image conversion not using file system

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rewriting

I would like to do image conversion/rewriting with PIL just using RAM memory. I have the image in bytes in RAM and I would like to convert it to some other format or possibly the same. I know I can do it like saving it in on the file system with some name, but I would like to do it just using RAM without touching the file system. I haven't found any examples. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) file object instead of a regular file as well with both PIL [`Image.open`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#image-open-function) and [`Image.save`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.save)

```
# somewhere earlier in the code:
# data = ...

from StringIO import StringIO
fd = StringIO(data)
image = Image.open(fd)
image.show()
```

There's also a [`frombuffer`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.frombuffer) function